List folders using ListBlobsByHierarchy using Azure SDK for cpp
I am using azure sdk for cpp, and I am using option ListBlobsByHierarchy.
When I use ListBlobsByHierarchy, I get result almost as I have expected, all the blobs are there, all the virtual directories are there.
The problems is with folders that are not virtual directories, not blobs.
If I create a blob folder1/folder2/blob.txt, in azure I will see folder1->folder2->blob.txt.
But if I try to list root directory and to get a folder1 as a result, it fails.
I have tried to use ListBlobs, but it reads whole container and implementing filter for root, or any other directory is complicated and very slow.
Is there an options or way to fetch that folder1 with ListBlobsByHierarchy?


Is there an options or way to fetch that folder1 with ListBlobsByHierarchy?

In my Azure Storage account, I had a folder structure be like:
  sample/
    data.xlsx
  sample/venkat1/
    demo.txt
    file.csv
    sample.pdf
    sample.wav
    samplecert.pfx
    temp2.jpg
    test.jpg  

Portal:

To list blobs hierarchically, you can use the  ListBlobsByHierarchy  method. However, if you want to list the root directory and get a folder1(sample) as a result, you can try using the ListBlobs method instead.
Code:
#include <azure/storage/blobs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat326123;AccountKey=T3czZpu1gZ0zzzzzzzzzw2zzz08xcs5p4Wu2+AStD9nyWw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    std::string containerName = "test";

    auto containerClient = Azure::Storage::Blobs::BlobContainerClient::CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, containerName);
    std::set<std::string> seenDirs;

    Azure::Storage::Blobs::ListBlobsOptions options;
    auto response = containerClient.ListBlobs(options);
    std::cout << "Listing top-level directories:" << std::endl;

    do {
        // List blobs and extract directories from blob names
        for (const auto& blob : response.Blobs) {
            std::string blobName = blob.Name;

            // Split the blob name by '/' to get top-level directories
            size_t pos = blobName.find('/');
            if (pos != std::string::npos) {
                std::string topLevelDir = blobName.substr(0, pos + 1); // Include '/' to indicate directory
                if (seenDirs.find(topLevelDir) == seenDirs.end()) {
                    std::cout << "  Directory: " << topLevelDir << std::endl;
                    seenDirs.insert(topLevelDir);
                }
            }
        }
        if (response.HasPage()) {
            response.MoveToNextPage();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    if (seenDirs.empty()) {
        std::cout << "No top-level directories found." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
Listing top-level directories:
  Directory: sample/

